# How do I check if the ssh connection is correctly set up?

Tags: ssh, connection, scp

I need to transfer data using scp from ubuntu server1 to ubuntu server2.
I have created and set up ssh credentials between the two servers.
How do I check if the ssh connection is correctly set up?

Comment: Are you just asking how to check if a connection can be made?  Or are you asking more of a security question?

Comment: you could try to create an ssh terminal session between the two computers. i.e. `ssh username@server2`.

Comment: Set up an `ssh` chain. `ssh` to `server1`, from there, `ssh` to `server2`, and `ssh` back to `server1`